# Kafka 0.8.2 ConsumerMetadataRequest always return ConsumerCoordinatorNotAvailableCode

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using [kafka 0.8.2](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/0.8.2.0/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.tgz), I want to use the fetch and commit offset API, as the document [said](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-OffsetCommit/FetchAPI):

> The offsets for a given consumer group are maintained by a specific broker called the offset coordinator. i.e., a consumer needs to issue its offset commit and fetch requests to this specific broker. It can discover the current offset coordinator by issuing a consumer metadata request

So I send a `ConsumerMetadataRequest`, instead of getting the correct response, I'm always get [ConsumerCoordinatorNotAvailableCode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-ErrorCodes)

> The broker returns this error code for consumer metadata requests or offset commit requests if the offsets topic has not yet been created.

If I use the [kafka 0.8.2beta](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/0.8.2-beta/kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.tgz) version, which doesn't have the issue.

Also I use the go client [sarama](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama), I have create the `__consumer_offsets` topic before fetch metadata. And here is my config:

```
broker.id=1
port=9091
host.name=192.168.33.10
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=data/9091
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.cleaner.enable=false
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found a similar problem. The issue is that the consumer has not issued a ConsumerMetadataRequest for the consumer group.

What I've found is that you have to send a ConsumerMetadataRequest and retry with back off if you receive a ConsumerCoordinatorNotAvailableCode returned as an error.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found, it's something occurred by my `Scale` version, when I use Scale's version of  `2.9.1`, it succeed, but failed in `2.10`. I'm not familiar with `Scala`, so I'm not deep in it.